# USB Ethernet only works for a few seconds

Tags: networking

I have a Dell D6000 USB-C dock connected to a Lenovo P50. The USB Ethernet interface only works for a few seconds after it's brought up, then it stops working. For example, if I am running ping to my route/gateway, it says "host unreachable". If I turn off the interface and turn it back on I'll see a few successful pings before it becomes unreachable. The same thing happens when I physically unplug and re-plug the Ethernet cable:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
From 192.168.1.124 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable # this is where I unplug the cable
From 192.168.1.124 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.124 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable # plugged the cable back in a waited a second...
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=1859 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=842 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=1.72 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=2.05 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=1.81 ms
```

ethtool doesn't show much for the interface:

```
$ sudo ethtool enp0s20f0u2u1i5 
Settings for enp0s20f0u2u1i5:
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

The same problem started happening in Linux Mint cinnamon. I switched to Pop!_OS and had the same problem. Tried Manjaro KDE, same problem. Fedora, same problem. So I've had the same problem across multiple distros and kernels. The last distro on which it was definitely working was KDE Neon and I believe I had it working on Fedora KDE as well. I can also confirm it is working on Windows. I'm now on Fedora 32 (Gnome) and still have the same problem. Below is output for some commands that might provide some useful insight

```
$ dmesg | grep enp0s20f0u2u1i5 
[    4.035631] cdc_ncm 2-2.1:1.5 enp0s20f0u2u1i5: renamed from usb0
[   12.812439] cdc_ncm 2-2.1:1.5 enp0s20f0u2u1i5: network connection: disconnected
[   12.844436] cdc_ncm 2-2.1:1.5 enp0s20f0u2u1i5: network connection: connected
[   13.002757] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s20f0u2u1i5: link becomes ready
[   75.212542] cdc_ncm 2-2.1:1.5 enp0s20f0u2u1i5: network connection: disconnected
[   81.436679] cdc_ncm 2-2.1:1.5 enp0s20f0u2u1i5: 1000 mbit/s downlink 1000 mbit/s uplink
[   81.468677] cdc_ncm 2-2.1:1.5 enp0s20f0u2u1i5: network connection: connected
```

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s20f0u2u1i5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:37:96:0d:c2:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.124/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s20f0u2u1i5
       valid_lft 604676sec preferred_lft 604676sec
    inet6 fe80::5760:8b51:4810:e509/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:5b:76:2f:cf:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 46:b7:f7:5d:22:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
$ modinfo cdc_ncm
filename:       /lib/modules/5.6.6-300.fc32.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/usb/cdc_ncm.ko.xz
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    USB CDC NCM host driver
author:         Hans Petter Selasky
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc0Dip00in*
alias:          usb:v1546p1010d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc0Dip00in*
alias:          usb:v1519p0443d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc0Dip00in*
alias:          usb:v12D1p*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc0Dip00in*
alias:          usb:v0930p*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc0Dip00in*
alias:          usb:v413Cp*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc0Dip00in*
alias:          usb:v413Cp81BCd*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc0Dip00in*
alias:          usb:v413Cp81BBd*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc0Dip00in*
alias:          usb:v1BC7p0036d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc0Dip00in*
alias:          usb:v0BDBp*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc0Dip00in*
depends:        usbnet
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cdc_ncm
vermagic:       5.6.6-300.fc32.x86_64 SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Fedora kernel signing key
sig_key:        7E:E3:7B:CE:53:8B:CA:A7:B5:4A:A8:CD:5E:E3:4C:2A:A7:52:9A:7A
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
signature:      7B:E0:1C:53:E0:A1:BC:75:97:0C:53:0C:E3:A2:BE:52:A3:02:D9:0B:
        98:56:AB:96:79:D0:1F:C8:4A:8E:E8:A0:89:18:F3:DD:66:3A:9F:F2:
        09:80:EC:C3:BE:96:62:6E:BB:AE:1B:41:AC:FE:F6:19:91:7A:2E:FB:
        13:C8:2C:5D:25:EF:71:9C:3B:A6:D1:24:CF:8F:35:C7:DF:53:49:30:
        24:24:D7:C3:2C:4C:CA:F2:CF:CE:7B:1F:21:2E:F3:D9:C8:6F:94:FA:
        65:B9:25:4D:1B:46:EE:75:1D:FF:CB:E4:C9:50:99:5F:56:CE:83:B1:
        E1:E9:87:ED:79:6D:2A:33:4A:FF:88:A3:AE:B7:0E:D5:44:A2:94:50:
        2B:1F:85:78:AA:B2:65:D4:28:42:0D:1D:D9:66:05:6B:10:A7:EF:FA:
        51:62:18:B9:BE:02:80:55:E1:80:21:43:22:F3:82:4A:C5:66:A1:23:
        EF:A0:0D:B6:DF:FE:19:E8:5E:BF:0D:34:A7:36:6B:69:93:7E:C4:42:
        04:D0:1C:47:78:94:1A:7D:45:2E:0C:04:7C:CD:81:00:E0:97:30:06:
        79:E5:04:9A:25:AD:01:87:6A:BE:06:9E:0B:C4:B9:9A:A6:06:48:CB:
        BC:A8:4C:60:E4:DC:5D:2C:C7:4E:19:9E:88:BD:63:AB:42:AC:7E:FF:
        BF:5D:4E:4F:9B:2C:B0:15:13:1D:4E:1D:96:EC:EC:8F:50:57:5C:8E:
        89:A7:32:7D:B4:3A:63:15:FB:45:D5:29:9C:AE:67:E2:6D:B4:66:28:
        7C:C8:70:8A:2F:65:91:D3:F4:0C:70:A3:2B:E1:60:9A:14:2E:BD:59:
        E4:C4:3A:10:E6:75:6E:DF:1D:92:4E:DC:EA:5E:27:F4:02:9C:1A:B9:
        86:E7:C7:BF:80:D7:48:4E:33:A9:AC:EF:B7:E1:19:28:49:23:7D:EF:
        23:D9:F5:E6:79:ED:02:86:1B:BE:06:9B:C2:81:A0:7D:39:71:9F:99:
        BC:71:9F:63:AA:59:B0:BC:28:0C:AB:C2:B7:43:F0:8E:B3:89:99:E1:
        B5:E1:F1:AE:EC:47:32:F5:64:D1:AF:61:04:BB:9C:A2:FA:6D:64:87:
        BA:A2:52:FA:79:1D:A1:A6:C2:37:D5:FE:23:BE:97:22:D2:B6:B6:8F:
        45:4C:F2:C6:10:BF:6D:F7:37:3B:25:ED:2C:12:3C:A3:FA:00:DB:C5:
        FB:87:19:01:6C:04:CD:4B:29:11:2E:7D:7A:0E:C1:AE:D0:3C:05:ED:
        F4:10:EF:00:B1:D8:BB:ED:6F:36:11:A5:1A:AE:AA:98:D3:D9:49:E7:
        81:4B:D8:23:B3:99:77:82:CD:58:3D:1F
parm:           prefer_mbim:Prefer MBIM setting on dual NCM/MBIM functions (bool)
```

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 3a
       serial: 02:50:6a:2a:d1:22
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.6.6-300.fc32.x86_64 firmware=36.77d01142.0 8000C-36.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:135 memory:c4c00000-c4c01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: c8:5b:76:2f:cf:8d
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.8-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:130 memory:c5700000-c571ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:2.1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u2u1i5
       serial: 0c:37:96:0d:c2:43
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ncm driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC NCM ip=192.168.1.124 link=yes multicast=yes
```

```
$ neofetch
          /:-------------:\          joe@localhost-live.lan1 
       :-------------------::        ----------------------- 
     :-----------/shhOHbmp---:\      OS: Fedora 32 (Workstation Edition) x86_64 
   /-----------omMMMNNNMMD  ---:     Host: 20EQS2VS00 ThinkPad P50 
  :-----------sMMMMNMNMP.    ---:    Kernel: 5.6.6-300.fc32.x86_64 
 :-----------:MMMdP-------    ---\   Uptime: 30 mins 
,------------:MMMd--------    ---:   Packages: 1684 (rpm) 
:------------:MMMd-------    .---:   Shell: bash 5.0.11 
:----    oNMMMMMMMMMNho     .----:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
:--     .+shhhMMMmhhy++   .------/   DE: GNOME 3.36.1 
:-    -------:MMMd--------------:    WM: Mutter 
:-   --------/MMMd-------------;     WM Theme: Adwaita 
:-    ------/hMMMy------------:      Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
:-- :dMNdhhdNMMNo------------;       Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
:---:sdNMMMMNds:------------:        Terminal: gnome-terminal 
:------:://:-------------::          CPU: Intel i7-6820HQ (8) @ 3.600GHz 
:---------------------://            GPU: NVIDIA Quadro M2000M 
                                     GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 
                                     Memory: 2209MiB / 15841MiB
```